# Filtering a DISTINCTCOUNT in DAX with a complex condition

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a table products with some signs of participation in certain promotions.
[image]

The condition of promotion work like this:
Take any product from set 1 **AND** take any product from set 2

There is a big table of sales

[image]

and table about regions for sales of point

[image]

I need to make a calculated measure for promotion 1 as the unique number salepoint_id for points that fulfill the condition promo 1

I prepared a scheme in powerpivot

[image]

Added calculated fields

[image]

And measures
[image]

Result correct

[image]

but:

1. The sales table is large and the calculated field is not the best approach
2. It is assumed in the table to use a hierarchy (Year/Quarter/Month, Region/Territory) and therefore the use Allexcept becomes impossible

How to create a calculated measure that counts the number of unique sale points have complied with the condition of promotion based on the context of the PivotTable?

[Download link example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwc4vbobpq3rtp5/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B01.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I solved my problem after many tortures but I think that it is too complicated and not optimal.  `PointPromoPerform:=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(prodpromo[promo_1]);CALCULATETABLE(prodpromo;not(ISBLANK(prodpromo[promo_1]));'sales'))=2` and  `dist_points:=SUMX(DISTINCT(sales[salepoint_id]);IF([PointPromoPerform];1;0))` . Maybe someone will give me a better solution?

Comment: Picked the best perfomance with same results (in 'prodpromo' replace "set 1" on 1 and "set 2" on 2): `PointPromoPerform:=and(MINX(CALCULATETABLE('prodpromo';'sales');prodpromo[promo_1‌​])=1;MAXX(CALCULATETABLE('prodpromo';'sales');prodpromo[promo_1‌​])=2)` . Second measure "dist_points" is same as my answer above.